# How to fix: SQLException during login process

Tags: sql

Whenever I tried to open SQL connection. I get this exception:

`sqlConn.Open()`

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory
>   Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This error happens if the sql server closes the connection. What credentials do you use?

From [msdn / social net](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/0a58d127-f532-44f1-8507-f9131228b5c1)

> The best is to check for any messages from SQL Server correlated to
>   the time of the failure - either in the Application EventLog or in the
>   ERRORLOG file (by default located in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG directory).  There is a chance they
>   provide more information to identify the root cause of the failure.